# How can I link this two sentences?

Tags: grammaticality, subordinate-clauses

What could be the best linking solutions for these two sencences separated from ";"?

> The urban project, with respect to the preservation of the village, envisages the recovery, restoration and reconversion of the spaces internal and external to the historical finds; **this will be done** /// **this,**  in order to ensure the integrity, the beauty and the emotions that these places stir up.

Comment: It's a little wordy, but "this will be done" is better than "this." Meanwhile, you could just cut out the middle man and say, "...to the historical finds in order to ensure the integrity...."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this will be done

is the better of your two choices since the proposal for the preservation of the village is still hypothetical and in the future.  You might also use

> This is being done...